# How to check if all items in list of RGB colors is in an image without a loop?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a list of RGB values as follows:

```
rgbL = [[20 45 40] [30 45 60] .... [70 50 100]]
```

Then, I have an image say, `img = cv.imread("location")`

Now, I want to change ALL RGB values of an image into (255, 0, 0) if the image RGB value is IN my list of RGB values (rgbL).

I was able to do this by this code:

```
for rgb in rgbL :

    k = list(filter(None, rgb[1:-1].split(" ")))
    r = int(k[0])
    g = int(k[1])
    b = int(k[2])

    img[np.all(img == (r, g, b), axis=-1)] = (255,0,0)
```

But the code above is taking too long because my "rgbL" list is too long.

Is there a way that I can do this without a loop? What is the best way to implement it in numpyish way?

Comment: Why not turn the list of colors into a `set` of colors?

Comment: why???? for each image, just take its dimensions, delete that image, create another image with the same dimension but with RGB on (255,0,0) it is more quick isn't it?

Comment: @user1438644 because that is not OP's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert your `rgbL` and `img` into numpy arrays. one way of doing it without loop:

```
sh = img.shape
img = img.reshape(-1, 3)
img[np.where(((rgbL[:,None,:]-img)==0).all(axis=2))[1]]=np.array([255,0,0])
img = img.reshape(sh)
```

which takes a difference of your image with every row of `rgbL` and checks for `all` zero difference in RGBs to replace using `np.where`.

sample `img` and output:

```
img:
[[ 20  45  40]
 [ 30  45  60]
 [  0   1   2]
 [ 70  50 100]
 [  4   5   6]]
rgbL:
[[ 20  45  40]
 [ 30  45  60]
 [ 70  50 100]]
Output:
[[255   0   0]
 [255   0   0]
 [  0   1   2]
 [255   0   0]
 [  4   5   6]]
```

***UPDATE***: Per OP's comment on converting string dict keys to numpy arrays:

```
rgbL = np.array([list(map(int,[s.strip() for s in key.strip('[').strip(']').strip(' ').split(' ') if s.strip()])) for key in rgb_dict.keys()])
```

Comment: I tried your code but I got an error. My rgbL is actually coming from a dictionary key.  So I tried list(rgbL.keys()) and I got this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple.  Sorry, I am still not so familiar with this.

Comment: @RJUy The error says it. convert your keys into a numpy array using `rgbL = np.array(whatever_list_of_keys)`. Lists are unhashable and cannot be dict keys. How do you have a list as a dict key? could you please copy a sample of your dict here?

Comment: I already did that "np.array(list(RGB_DIC.keys()))" but I got another error: IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: I cannot help much by just an error message, unless I see what you are attempting to do. I can guess you have it as a list and not a numpy array. Could you please copy a sample of your dictionary here so I can help better? Thank you.

Comment: Here a sample RGB_DIC values:  The Key holds the RGB values, that is why I used RGB_DIC.keys(). 

{'[182 192 179]': 5, '[190 200 187]': 5, '[190 203 189]': 5, '[147 166 157]': 5, '[103 116 108]': 6, '[155 177 165]': 6, '[183 197 185]': 5}

Comment: Your keys are not lists. They are strings. You need to convert them to lists first. I will update an answer to fix your problem. Also, it is a strange way of storing RGBs as strings like this.You might want to consider storing them as values along with other value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  I am actually still new to this stuff.  I am still not so familiar, for now I have done that way but if my algo works I'll refactor my codes.

Comment: @RJUy no worries. Please find the update in my post to answer your issue. Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried it just now, but I got this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213978/discussion-between-ehsan-and-rj-uy).

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm mentioned above is *O(length of rgbL * size of image)*

We can bring it down to *O(length of the rgbL + size of image)*

```
set_rgbl = set(rgbL)
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
BLUE_COLOR = (255, 0, 0)

for h in range(0, height):
    for w in range(0, width):
        if list(img[h, w]) in set_rgbl:
            img[h, w] = BLUE_COLOR
```

What happens here is that we created a set of rgbL values. The insert in set is constant time operation. Same holds for lookup. Hence, when we are iterating over every pixel values in image for every pixel we spend *O(1)* time. This leads to improvement in our time complexity.

Hope that helps.