# Convert all values in numpy array if that value found in a list of numpy array without MemoryError

Tags: python, numpy

I have a colored image (img) and I want to change ALL RGB values of that image if the RGB value found in my list of RGB values (rgbL) without doing a loop.  How to do this in a Numpyish way.

```
img = cv2.imread("image location") 
rgbL = [[0, 0, 113],[107, 9, 0], [ 98, 131, 119], 
        [108, 124, 113], [108, 125, 114], ..... , [108, 125, 116], 
        [108, 127, 112]]

newVal = # LINE OF CODES THAT DOES THE JOB
```

Got a working code @ [How to check if all items in list of RGB colors is in an image without a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61829495/how-to-check-if-all-items-in-list-of-rgb-colors-is-in-an-image-without-a-loop/61829844#61829844)

But when my rbgL is too long, I got this error: MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (3047, 1048576, 3) and data type int32

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. Please show what you've tried already and how it is different from what you want.

Comment: Didn't this post resolve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61829495/how-to-check-if-all-items-in-list-of-rgb-colors-is-in-an-image-without-a-loop/61829844#61829844

Comment: I have updated my post.  That does the job but I got a MemoryError when my rgbL is too long.

Comment: Isn't this to be expected? No loop -> high memory usage. It is a compromise.

Comment: if you are comparing images, better use `np.uint8`. So `(3047, 1048576, 3)` is about 9.6GB, which could be handled with 16GB system. Else you need to cut your `rgbL` into smaller lists and do a loop.

Comment: Given the image size (etc), does that (3047, 1048576, 3) size (for the return value) look reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this before the answer in your linked post:

```
rgbL = np.array(rgbL, dtype=np.uint8)
img = img.astype('uint8')
```

That would make an array of shape `(3047, 1048576, 3)` into (3047*1048576*3)*8~8GB